# How to deploy an application from a monorepo with a shared library?

Tags: reactjs, vite, netlify, monorepo, pnpm

I'm trying to deploy an app that is on a monorepo that imports a library  that is inside this same repo, I'm using pnpm as packager manager

**pnpm-workspace.yaml**

```
packages:
  - "packages/common/ui"
  - "packages/main-app"
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "monorepo",
    "private": true,
    "workspaces": [
        "packages/common/ui",
        "packages/main-app"
    ],
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=18.12.1"
    },
    "packageManager": "pnpm@7.29.1"
}
```

**packages/common/ui/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@monorepo/common-ui",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.1.0",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "main": "./dist/common-ui.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/common-ui.es.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/common-ui.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/common-ui.umd.js"
    },
    "./dist/style.css": "./dist/style.css"
  }
}
```

**packages/main-app/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "monorepo/main-app",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "monorepo/common-ui": "link:../common/ui",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

On my machine, everything works fine with command:

```
$ pnpm --filter @monorepo/main-app build
```

or with command:

```
$ cd packages/main-app && pnpm run build
```

but on netlify I'm getting this error

```
10:47:50 PM: $ pnpm build
10:47:50 PM: > @monorepo/main-app@0.0.0 build /opt/build/repo/packages/main-app
10:47:50 PM: > tsc && vite build
10:47:51 PM: src/App.tsx(1,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@monorepo/common-ui' or its corresponding type declarations.
10:47:51 PM:  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 2. (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-2)
10:47:51 PM: ​
10:47:51 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
10:47:51 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
10:47:51 PM: ​
10:47:51 PM:   Error message
10:47:51 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: pnpm build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
10:47:51 PM: ​
10:47:51 PM:   Error location
10:47:51 PM:   In build.command from netlify.toml:
10:47:51 PM:   pnpm build
10:47:51 PM: ​
10:47:51 PM:   Resolved config
10:47:51 PM:   build:
10:47:51 PM:     base: /opt/build/repo/packages/main-app
10:47:51 PM:     command: pnpm build
10:47:51 PM:     commandOrigin: config
10:47:51 PM:     environment:
10:47:51 PM:       - NODE_VERSION
10:47:51 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/packages/main-app/dist
10:47:51 PM:     publishOrigin: config
10:47:51 PM:   redirects:
10:47:51 PM:     - from: /*
      status: 200
      to: index.html
  redirectsOrigin: config
Caching artifacts
```

It's like **@monorepo/common-ui** is not built when netlify tries to build **@monorepo/main-app**.

Did I need to have post-install script somewhere?

Am I missing a configuration somewhere?
Do I need to add a post-install script in some package?

Should I upload the package **@monorepo/common-ui** already built and track the dist dir on git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to add a script called "prepare" on package.json like this:

```
{
  "name": "@monorepo/common-ui",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "prepare": "pnpm run build"
  },
  ...
}
```

More details here:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#prepare-and-prepublish